# scikit-learn: fitting data into chunks vs fitting it all at once

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn

I am using scikit-learn to build a classifier, which works on (somewhat large) text files. I need a simple bag-of-words features at the moment, therefore I tried using TfidfVectorizer/HashingVectorizer/CountVectorizer to obtain the feature vectors.

However, processing the entire train data at once to obtain the feature vectors results in memory error in numpy/scipy (depending on which vectorizer I use).

When extracting text features from the raw text: if I fit the data to the vectorizer in chunks, will that be the same as fitting the entire data at once?

To illustrate this with code, is the following:

```
vectoriser = CountVectorizer() # or TfidfVectorizer/HashingVectorizer
train_vectors = vectoriser.fit_transform(train_data)
```

different from the following:

```
vectoriser = CountVectorizer() # or TfidfVectorizer/HashingVectorizer


start = 0
while start < len(train_data):
    vectoriser.fit(train_data[start:(start+500)])
    start += 500

train_vectors = vectoriser.transform(train_data)
```

Comment: Is there any place in your code where you could free up your memory, e.g. by getting rid of the references to already parsed text data? Or could you switch to 64 bit Python and/or a different OS (Windows will cap the memory allocated to every process, Ubuntu won't, for example).

Comment: @AleksanderLidtke, thank you for the comment. To answer your questions: 
1. I can't free up more memory. I don't load the entire text files into memory, I only pass filenames to scikit-learn vectorizer. Meaning if any optimisation of memory usage could be done, that is inside scikit-learn.
2. Changing to another OS will be problematic.
3. I don't think the problem is because of using too much memory anyway. I've seen my python applications using up to 1.8GB of RAM before, while now it crashes at about 500MB. Should I probably open another question and post the exception traces I receive?

Comment: No problem. And right, I see. I don't know the underlying workings of scikit, I only use a few parts of it. Perhaps you could read the data yourself, then extract the relevant bits, and use those with some more memory efficient function of scikit? Or write to the developers? Also, could be that the process that runs out of memory is a child process of your Python process. Look to see if there's anything taking up loads of memory when you run the script.

Comment: @DarkMatter scikit-learn has no problem using all 8GB of my RAM (and more). It is possible that you get a memory error because it wants to allocate a huge matrix in memory though. So the RAM is actually never used but you still have a memory issue. Looks like a legit question to me ;).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on the vectorizer you are using.

**CountVectorizer** counts occurences of the words in the documents.
It outputs for each document a `(n_words, 1)` vector with the number of times each word appears in the document. `n_words` is the **total number of words in the documents** (aka the size of the vocabulary).
It also fits a vocabulary so that you can introspect the model (see what word is important, etc.). You can have a look at it using `vectorizer.get_feature_names()`.

When you fit it on your first 500 documents, the vocabulary will only be made of the words from the 500 documents. Say there are 30k of them, `fit_transform` outputs a `500x30k` sparse matrix.
Now you `fit_transform` again with the 500 next documents, but they contain only 29k words so you get a `500x29k` matrix...
Now, how do you align your matrices to make sure all documents have a consistent representation?
I can't think of an easy way to do this at the moment.

With **TfidfVectorizer** you have another issue, that is the inverse document frequency: to be able to compute document frequency you need to see all the documents at once.
However a `TfidfVectorizer` is just a `CountVectorizer` followed by a `TfIdfTransformer`, so if you manage to get the output of the `CountVectorizer` right you can then apply a `TfIdfTransformer` on the data.

With **HashingVectorizer** things are different: there is no vocabulary here.

```
In [51]: hvect = HashingVectorizer() 
In [52]: hvect.fit_transform(X[:1000])       
<1000x1048576 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
 with 156733 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Here there are not 1M+ different words in the first 1000 documents, yet the matrix we get has 1M+ columns.
The `HashingVectorizer` does not store the words in memory. This makes it more memory efficient and makes sure that the matrices it returns **always have the same number of columns**.
So you don't have the same problem as with the `CountVectorizer` here.

This is probably the best solution for the batch processing you described.  There are a couple of cons, namely that you cannot get the idf weighting and that you do not know the mapping between words and your features.

The [HashingVectorizer documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.HashingVectorizer.html) references an example that does [out-of-core classification on text data](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/plot_out_of_core_classification.html). It may be a bit messy but it does what you'd like to do.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**:
If you have too much data, `HashingVectorizer` is the way to go.
If you still want to use `CountVectorizer`, a possible workaround is to fit the vocabulary yourself and to pass it to your vectorizer so that you only need to call `tranform`.

Here's an example you can adapt:

```
import re
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer

news = fetch_20newsgroups()
X, y = news.data, news.target
```

Now the approach that does not work:

```
# Fitting directly:
vect = CountVectorizer()
vect.fit_transform(X[:1000])
<1000x27953 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
with 156751 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Note the size of the matrix we get.
Fitting the vocabulary 'manually':

```
def tokenizer(doc):
    # Using default pattern from CountVectorizer
    token_pattern = re.compile('(?u)\\b\\w\\w+\\b')
    return [t for t in token_pattern.findall(doc)]

stop_words = set() # Whatever you want to have as stop words.
vocabulary = set([word for doc in X for word in tokenizer(doc) if word not in stop_words])

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=vocabulary)
X_counts = vectorizer.transform(X[:1000])
# Now X_counts is:
# <1000x155448 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
#   with 149624 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
#   
X_tfidf = tfidf.transform(X_counts)
```

On your example you'll need to first build the **entire** matrix X_counts (for all documents) before applying the tfidf transform.

Comment: Great explanation, thank you! I think if I do two passes through the training data, doing only "fit" during the first one and then "transform" during the second one, this fixes the CountVectorizer problem you mention, as this firstly builds the vocabulary and then gives the vectors. However this seems to be a lot more inefficient, as fit calls fit_transform (?) inside CountVectorizer, so I'm basically doing the same work twice. What I'm still not quite sure about is: will all that work with a TfidfVectorizer?

Comment: Doing 2 passes works if you can fit on all your documents at once. Otherwise you could collect the vocabulary "manually" and pass it to the CountVectorizer constructor so that it works with a fixed vocabulary. To get a TfidfVectorizer you can just use a TfidfTransformer on the output of CountVectorizer. I am surprised to see that fit indeed calls fit_transform! A possible workaround would be to iterate through your documents to build the vocabulary yourself.

Comment: why do I need to fit all the documents at once? What I would suppose that happens is that every time another batch is fitted, the vocabulary is extended. Thus, when transforming the data later, the final vocabulary, which is extracted from all the documents even that in chunks, is used. Sorry if I fail to see something obvious :(

Comment: Otherwise, thank you for the answer. I will accept it, but please update it with thoughts on our conversation here, so it is as helpful as possible for others :)

Comment: Unfortunately the vectorizer is fit from scratch each time you call fit. The behaviour you describe would be nice in your case though. I'd suggest you construct the vocabulary yourself, I'll edit my answer for that. Otherwise if you have too much data HashingVectorizer is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a text-feature extracting expert, but based on the documentation and my other classifier base experiences:

> If I do several fits on chunks of the training data, will that be the
>   same as fitting the entire data at once?

You can't directly merge the extracted features, because you will get **different** importances i.e. `weights` for the same token/word getting from the different chunk in **different** proportion to other words of the chunk, represented with a **different** key.

You can use any feature extracting method, the usefulness of the result depends of the task, I think.

But if you can use different chunks' **different** features for classification on the **same** data. Once you get several different outputs with the features you acquired with **the same feature extracting method**(or you can use different extracting method too), you can use them as an input to a "merging" mechanism like `bagging`, `boosting` etc. 
Actually after the entire process above in most case you will get a **better** final output, than you fed the full file in one "full-featured" but even a simple classifier.

Comment: I must say I'm not entirely sure I understand your answer. Using an ensemble method to do my classification sounds indeed as it would be a great idea. However, this doesn't answer my question on how to extract features (of unseen data as well). I can easily use different vectorizers for the different "bursts" in the training process, but which vectorizer should I use when unseen data arrives, which I want to turn into a feature vector to classify? I haven't implemented a method such as bagging before, so the answer to that might be completely obvious...

Comment: @DarkMatter your answer exactly was as follows: 

**"So my question is: If I do several fits on chunks of the training data, will that be the same as fitting the entire data at once?"**, but please update your question, to fit exactly to your needs, and I try to answer or you can open a new question.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I updated the question accordingly, hopefully it is clearer now. The code example explains best what I am asking.

Comment: @DarkMatter I see now that I answered your question, but maybe it was a bit cloudy, so I updated my answer see "with the features you acquired".