# scikit-learn: Memory Error when extracting features

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scikit-learn

Following the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31784011/scikit-learn-fitting-data-into-chunks-vs-fitting-it-all-at-once), I decided to post another question regarding the weird memory error that I get while extracting features in scikit-learn. The following code works as expected:

```py
import os
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

data = []
for i in range(0, 1000):
   filename = "a.txt"
   data.append(os.path.join(DATA_DIR, filename))

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(encoding = 'utf-8-sig', input = 'filename')
vectors = vectorizer.fit_transform(data)
```

However, if I change the range to (0, 2000) it gives me a Memory Error with the following trace:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\main.py", line 16, in <module>
vectors = vectorizer.fit_transform(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 817, in fit_transform
self.fixed_vocabulary_)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 769, in _count_vocab
values = np.ones(len(j_indices))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 178, in ones
a = empty(shape, dtype, order)
MemoryError
```

Notes:

- the file is about 200 000 characters / 40 000 words.
- OS is Windows 10.
- the python process takes about 340MB RAM at the moment of Memory Error.
- I've seen my python processes taking about 1.8GB before and there was never a problem. So Windows killing the process because it's trying to use too much memory doesn't seem to be the case here.
- I keep receiving the error even if I restrict the vocabulary size.

I will very much appreciate it if someone explains to me what's going on... Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'll assume you are trying to transform 2000 different files and not 2000 times  the same file, although you talked about 'the file'. Can you tell us what the size of the vocabulary after your run for `range(0, 1000)`? Also, all your files are about the same size (40k words)? In the same language ;)?

Comment: @user3914041 I tried it with the SAME file at the end, just to demonstrate how weird the error is. It gives the error with different files (with different content, but pretty much of the same size) as well though (which is the problem...). The vocabulary size I get after I run for range(0, 1000) is **5063**. And yes, the language is the same :D