# Result too large when using scikit linear_kernel for TF-IDF computation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science, tf-idf, recommendation-engine

I am new in python and currently trying to develop a content based recommender system. I am reading a csv file with about 60,000 rows and using TfidfVectorizer.fit_transform which makes a matrix size (63098, 9081) and then apply linear_kernel that then crashes and returns the error RuntimeError: nnz of the result is too large.

```
tf = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(1, 3), min_df=100, stop_words='english')
tfidf_matrix = tf.fit_transform(ds['description'])
result = linear_kernel(tfidf_matrix, tfidf_matrix)
```

Logs shows the supposed result would be 20gb in size. Is there a way to chunk the data and how to apply that in my current structure? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tfidf were popular some 5-10 years ago. These days word embeddings  like `word2vec` are considered mainstream for text processing.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are using all unique words in your data to create the `TfidfVectorizer`
The shape of your matrix will be `No. of documents * No. of unique words`, your system's current memory might not support this size, to avoid the memory error you can limit the matrix size using the `max_features` parameter as mentioned in the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html)

A size of `5000` or `10000` is normally used, but you can try different values and see what suits you.

Comment: Even if I set the max_features to 100 with 60,000 items the session still crashes after warning tcmalloc: large alloc 28770443264 bytes.

Comment: Does it abort the execution or keeps running post this warning, because this is not an error message this is a warning? Can you check the same on 1000 rows only to see if this still appears? Also edit the question with complete error message.

Comment: Thank you for replying. The session crashes every time because of the large result. At 1,000 rows the script runs perfectly but at around 30,000 it returns that error. What I want to know is if there is a more memory efficient way for TFIDF like chunking the result if that is possible.

Comment: In sklearn language this is called partial_fit but as per my knowledge the tfidf doesn’t have this feature because the way it works it needs the complete dataset to calculate the weights. But if your requirement permits you can try HashingVectorizer, there is an excellent post on SO which you can find here - [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31784011/scikit-learn-fitting-data-into-chunks-vs-fitting-it-all-at-once) or you can follow the post which has few more alternative ways to use.