# How load huge data json in jupyter on VSCode

Tags: python, json, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm doing a sentiment analysis for my master's degree and i'm working with jupyter nootebook on VSCode on Ubuntu 20.04. I have a problem: when I try to load my file (12gb) my kernel dieds. So I splitted my file into 6 of 2 gb each, but also in this case I can't load all file to create a dataframe in order to work with it. So i would to ask how can I load each file, create a database and then storage all together into one dataframe to work with it?
I tried to load one file in this way:

```
import pandas as pd

filename = pd.read_json("xaa.json", lines=True, chunksize= 200000)
```

and in this case the kernel didn't die. From this point, how could I save this filename into a dataframe? I know that in this way I splitted one file into many files of 200000 lines, but I don't know how storage all this chunks into a first dataframe.
Thank you for the attention and I'm sorry for the banal question.

Comment: you want to add each chunksize= 200000 to a csv? did i understand correctly?

Comment: Thank you @RoseGod for the answer. I try to explain what i want: in each file there are 1000000 of lines, but if I try to import all line together with a for cycle, my kernel on Ubuntu dies. So I thought to do it in this way, but I don't know how I can storage all import in a dataframe.

Comment: The problem is you have to much data to store it in a dataframe. when you load the data into a dataframe it is stored in your ram and because you have to much data there is not enough ram causing it to crash. the solution is to load it in chunks and do what you need the question is what do you need to do after you loaded the data?

Comment: Thank you @RoseGod, with your question I'm sure to let you know what is the point. At this time I want to storage all chunks (maybe if into each file I have 1000000 of lines in this way I have 5 chunks of 200000) into a dataframe, because I want to do a sentimental anlysis on this text data. Once I have the dataframe, I could do manipolation on rows and columns to do all I want. Thank you for you patience and attention.

Comment: you cant storage all the file into a dateframe even if you load it in chunks because at the end the amount of data is more than your ram can handle. one option is to get more ram  the other option is to change you sentiment analysis so it doesnt perform on all the dataset but performs on chunks of the dataset. this question can maybe help you   [scikit-learn: fitting data into chunks vs fitting it all at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31784011/scikit-learn-fitting-data-into-chunks-vs-fitting-it-all-at-once).

Answer (score 2):

I want to post my solution: first of all I chose to make my IDE read all data in this way:

```
import glob
import json

files  = list(glob.iglob('Tesi/Resources/Twitter/*.json'))

tweets_data = []
for file in files:
   tweets_file = open(file, "r", encoding='utf-8')

     for line in tweets_file:
       tweet = json.loads(line)
       tweets_data.append(tweet)

tweets_file.close()
```

Then I defined a function to flat all tweets in order to load all in one dataframe.